# Other engineering disciplines have rigorous process which addresses the major risks

Tags: risk-analysis

Other engineering disciplines have rigorous process which addresses the major risks involved in the undertaking of any project. If software engineering is to borrow such a practice how can it add value?

Comment: Need a short answer of this question

Comment: Other engineering disciplines have something that software will never have: laws of physics to guide them.  It's no more possible to make software engineering that rigorous than it is to make writing prose or poetry so.